# Problema ao fazer build react native em monorepo

Tags: react-native, expo, yarn

Eu tenho um monorepo com 4 apps duas react js, uma adonis js, e agora criei a mobile em react native expo bare workflow, com o expo sdk 43 ouve melhorias em questão do monorepo, eu configurei conforme a documentação o metro config, estou a ter um erro um erro de dependecia na hora que faço  `yarn android --variant=release` retorna-me o seguinte erro.

```
      Error: Unable to resolve module react-native from /Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/expo/build/Expo.fx.js: react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
    ../../node_modules/expo/node_modules
    ../../node_modules

  If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
  1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
  2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
  3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
  4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    2 | // load remote logging for compatibility with custom development clients
    3 | import './environment/logging.fx';
  > 4 | import './environment/react-native-logs.fx';
      |                       ^
    5 | // load expo-asset immediately to set a custom `source` transformer in React Native
    6 | import 'expo-asset';
    7 | import Constants, { ExecutionEnvironment } from 'expo-constants';
      at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:234:15)
      at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
      at Object.resolve (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42)
      at resolve (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
      at /Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:645:26
      at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
      at resolveDependencies (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
      at /Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:329:33
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (/Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:24)
  info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

  > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
  Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  21 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 18 up-to-date
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "set-value" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "set-value" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "get-stream" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "clone" package.
  (node:2377) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
  Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
  (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "set-value" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "set-value" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "get-stream" package.
  ⚠️  Cannot resolve the path to "clone" package.
  (node:2464) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /Volumes/Dados/Websites/meufole/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
  Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
  (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Já apaguei as node_modules e fiz o clean do metro e nada resolveu

metro config

```
      // Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
  const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config')

  const path = require('path')

  // Find the workspace root, this can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
  const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..')
  const projectRoot = __dirname

  const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot)

  // 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
  config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot]
  // 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages, and in what order
  config.resolver.nodeModulesPath = [
    path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
    path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules')
  ]

  module.exports = config
```

Configuração do yarn workspaces

```
  {
    "name": "meufole",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "yarn workspaces run build",
      "test": "yarn workspaces run test",
      "ejected": "yarn workspace @meufole/mobile"
    },
    "workspaces": {
      "packages": [
        "apps/*",
        "packages/*"
      ],
      "nohoist": [
        "**/@adonisjs",
        "**/@adonisjs/**",
        "**/@rocketseat",
        "**/@rocketseat/**",
        "**/adonis-scheduler",
        "**/adonis-scheduler/**",
        "**/adonis-sentry",
        "**/adonis-sentry/**"
      ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@meufole/eslint-config": "*"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom eu acabei resolvendo por isso vou deixar aqui como resposta caso alguém passe pelo o mesmo.

Eu tinha configurado o meu metro bundler, para `watchFolders` e `nodeModulesPath` para saber onde ir buscar as dependencias.

Eu segui a documentação de exemplo de criar monorepo na documentação do expo e pequei a config do metro no site.

Porem eu pesquisei a documentação do `expo/metro-config` e reparei que eles usam `nodeModulesPaths` e não `nodeModulesPath` como eu estava a usar. Então o que eu fiz troquei na minha config `nodeModulesPath` por `nodeModulesPaths` e assim ele vai procurar as dependencias que precisa tanto na raiz do meu monorepo como no meu projecto mobile o problema era esse.

Então a minha config do metro bundler ficou assim.

```
  // Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
  const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config')

  const path = require('path')

  // Find the workspace root, this can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
  const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..')
  const projectRoot = __dirname

  const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot)

  // 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
  config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot]
  // 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages, and in what order
  config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
    path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
    path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules')
  ]

  module.exports = config
```